# Repeating initials in quotations autocite

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` in Overleaf. I am adding citations from sample.bib by using `\autocite{position}`. The current settings are like below:

```
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, bibstyle = authortitle,giveninits=true]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
```

First quotation contains first letters of first name, as well as surnames, title, publisher and so on.

[image]

Second quotation gives only surnames and title.

[image]

The question is - how can I make the name initials repeat? In the second and next quotations I would also like to see inits: in this example it would be again "K.A. Tranter, T. Stuart-Hill i J.Parker". It seems it should be easy fix, but cannot find an answer to that.

Secondly, what should I do if I wanted to repeat also the year? I guess there should be two ways - first being repeating only year again, and second repeating the full citation again?

Comment: Please only ask about one issue per question. That makes your question easier to answer, answers easier to evaluate and your question more useful for future visitors. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864. I focussed on your first question (the one also mentioned in the title). For your second question you should ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `giveninits=true,` active, which shortens given names to initials, this is as easy as changing the name format of `labelname` to `given-family`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite{sigfridsson}
sit \autocite{nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: M. Nussbaum, Aristotle’s ‘De Motu Animalium’.]